# How to expose a Kubernetes service on a specific Nodeport?

Tags: service, kubernetes

I have create a pod with the below yaml definition.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: praveensripati/docker-demo:1.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
```

And now I expose the pod, which creates a service.

```
kubectl expose pod myapp-pod --type=NodePort
```

The port 3000 on the container is exposed to port 31728 on the nodes. And I am able to do access the page using curl on port 31728.

```
kubectl get service myapp-pod
NAME        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
myapp-pod   NodePort   10.107.254.254   <none>        3000:31728/TCP   5s
```

This time I wanted to expose the service not a random port, but on port 80. And so I specify the port number as 80, by using --port. The service details are a bit odd. It says that port 80 on the container is exposed to port 31316 on the nodes. Also, I am able to access the page using curl on the random port (31316 in this case) and not port 80.

```
kubectl expose pod myapp-pod --type=NodePort --target-port=3000 --port=80

kubectl get service myapp-pod
NAME        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
myapp-pod   NodePort   10.105.123.73   <none>        80:31316/TCP   12s
```

I am not able to expose a service on a specific port and not on a random port. I tried a few combinations and read the k8s documentation, but no success.

How do I expose a service on a specific port instead of a random port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer your query here.

> Also, I am able to access the page using curl on the random port
>   (31316 in this case) and not port 80.

`-- Because, kubernetes exposed the port 31316 on the host (maps to the service) and hence it can be accessed on host:31316.`

```
-- Service port is visible only within the kubernetes cluster. You can exec into a pod container and do a curl on servicename:service port instead of the NodePort.
```

Note the terms - `container port:` the port container listens on. `Service port:` the port where kubernetes service is exposed on cluster internal ip and mapped to the container port. `Nodeport:` the port exposed on the host and mapped to kubernetes service.

Comment: See better answer a few posts below (by @Rico): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52523675/657067

Answer (score 43):

Your question is about exposing the NodePort type of service on a specific port. For that you need to specify the `nodePort` field under `ports` in your service definition.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    nodePort: 32321
  type: NodePort
```

Note that it has to be within a given range provided in the configs. Which defaults to `30000-32767`. This range can be specified in the [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) configs using the `--service-node-port-range` option.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Unless `nodePort` is specified in service definition yaml, k8s randomly allocates a port between 30000-32767. Also, note that, `kubectl expose pod ... type=nodePort ...`  does *not* have an option to specify `nodePort` in its arguments. One has to create a definition file and then do a `kubectl apply -f`to get the desired port. Or do a `kubectl patch` after random assigment.

Comment: As the upvote number shows, this answer clearly addresses the OP's question.

Answer (score 9):

When an existing Dashboard service already exists, remove it.

`kubectl delete service kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system`

Expose the Dashboard deployment as a NodePort.

`kubectl expose deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system --type=NodePort`

The above will assign a random port >= 30000. So use the Patch command to assign the port to a known, unused and desired port >= 30000.

`kubectl patch service kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system --type='json' --patch='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/ports/0/nodePort", "value":30000}]'`

Caution: [Never expose your dashboard publicly without authentication.](https://www.wired.com/story/cryptojacking-tesla-amazon-cloud/)

Answer (score 8):

If your cluster does not have a LoadBalancer Provider, you can specify [externalIPs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips) in IP of nodes' network interface.

For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:   
  type: ClusterIP
  externalIPs:
    - 125.100.99.101 # Node1-IP
    - 125.100.99.102 # Node2-IP
    - 192.168.55.112 # Node2-IP2
  selector:
    pod: nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80      
    - name: https
      port: 443
```

This will listen **80** and **443** on the specified node, and forward to the nginx service.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the only way I found to do it without modifying the files was:

```
k expose --type=NodePort deployment nginx --port 80 --name nginx-ep-patch  --overrides '{ "apiVersion": "v1","spec":{"ports": [{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":80,"nodePort":30080}]}}'
service/nginx-ep-patch exposed
```

In this way we path online the configuration and the port 30080 has been exposed:

```
$ k describe svc nginx-ep-patch
Name:                     nginx-ep-patch
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=nginx
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.96.51.148
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30080/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.6:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Answer (score 1):

we can expose Kubernetes service on specific node port.

Port value must be between 30000-32767.

We can expose service to specific port of below service types:

1. NodePort
2. LoadBalancer

Find the sample myservice.yaml file below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  type: NodePort/LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    nodePort: 32062
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    appone: app1
    app: test
```

Note: In above service yaml file we can specify service type either **NodePort** or **Loadbalancer**.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to use kubectl commands, you can create a NodePort service with a specified port using `create nodeport` command:

```sh
kubectl create nodeport NAME [--tcp=port:targetPort] [--dry-run=server|client|none]
```

For example:

```sh
kubectl create service nodeport myservice --node-port=31000 --tcp=3000:80
```

You can check Kubectl reference for more:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-service-nodeport-em-

Comment: This will work although you may need to dry-run to yaml and make sure the spec selector matches your pod

Answer (score 0):

**Below you will find two working manifests that expose ArgoCD**

1. Service NodePort on port 30k which is recommended only for dev usage not for production
2. Ingress which is the preferred method to expose a service

**Node1:** If the service works with HTTPS one will need to deal with provisioning a valid certificate for the ingress.

**Note2:** The Ingress config posted is from Microk8s ingress

Post comments for guidance or other questions.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-30k-node-port
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30000
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: argocd
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are . Please [edit✏️] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.