# Unable to implicitly expose a deployment in kubernetes with nodePort without editing yaml files

Tags: kubernetes, service, kubectl

I am trying to expose a deployment named webapp-servcie via a NodePort.

Requirements:

```
Type: NodePort 
targetPort: 8080 
port: 8080 
nodePort: 30080 
selector: simple-webapp
```

The service is supposed to look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - targetPort: 8080
      port: 8080
      nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    name: simple-webapp
```

When I try to implicitly expose the deployment I cannot set the NodePort from the command line. This is the command I am using:

```
kubectl expose deployment simple-webapp-deployment --name=webapp-service --port=8080 --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

This command provides the following YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: simple-webapp
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I am unable to define the Nodeport with the command. There is no flag available for me to use to set it. Therefore I have to edit the yaml manually to add it in under spec.

If I try to create a service implicitly without without exposing the deployment, I can specify the nodeport but I cannot select my deployment implicitly also it gives my port a name which I don't really care about.

```
kubectl create service nodeport webapp-service --tcp 8080:8080 --node-port=30080   --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

creates the yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: webapp-service
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    nodePort: 30080
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: webapp-service
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Is there a way for the sake of time and efficiency that I can create the service the way I need it to appear implicitly or will I always need to edit YAML? If not, is this a shortcoming of kubernetes or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

How about --type flag?

```
kubectl expose deployment simple-webapp-deployment --name=webapp-service --port=8080 --dry-run=client --type=NodePort -o yaml
```

Comment: ```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: simple-webapp
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```
Still doesn't give me the nodePort 30080 that needs to be specified.

Comment: @TylerTharp i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522570/how-to-expose-a-kubernetes-service-on-a-specific-nodeport

You can try the solutions from here. Use the --overrides flag or run another patch command.

Comment: This is a solution, but it's a pretty big workaround for something that should be pretty simple.